# Fatal Exception : unable to start activity componentinfo

Tags: android

I have problems running this app, it crashes immediately after starting. I'm practicing with fragments and I don't know where is the problem. I post the error log and my code. Thank you for your help :)

```
09-27 07:08:43.554: E/AndroidRuntime(1212): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-27 07:08:43.554: E/AndroidRuntime(1212): Process: com.example.rssfeed, PID: 1212
09-27 07:08:43.554: E/AndroidRuntime(1212): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.rssfeed/com.example.rssfeed.RssfeedActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment
09-27 07:08:43.554: E/AndroidRuntime(1212):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
09-27 07:08:43.554: E/AndroidRuntime(1212):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
09-27 07:08:43.554: E/AndroidRuntime(1212):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
09-27 07:08:43.554: E/AndroidRuntime(1212):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
09-27 07:08:43.554: E/AndroidRuntime(1212):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
09-27 07:08:43.554: E/AndroidRuntime(1212):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
09-27 07:08:43.554: E/AndroidRuntime(1212):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
09-27 07:08:43.554: E/AndroidRuntime(1212):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-27 07:08:43.554: E/AndroidRuntime(1212):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
09-27 07:08:43.554: E/AndroidRuntime(1212):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
09-27 07:08:43.554: E/AndroidRuntime(1212):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
09-27 07:08:43.554: E/AndroidRuntime(1212):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-27 07:08:43.554: E/AndroidRuntime(1212): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment
09-27 07:08:43.554: E/AndroidRuntime(1212):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
09-27 07:08:43.554: E/AndroidRuntime(1212):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
09-27 07:08:43.554: E/AndroidRuntime(1212):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
09-27 07:08:43.554: E/AndroidRuntime(1212):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
09-27 07:08:43.554: E/AndroidRuntime(1212):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
09-27 07:08:43.554: E/AndroidRuntime(1212):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
09-27 07:08:43.554: E/AndroidRuntime(1212):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
09-27 07:08:43.554: E/AndroidRuntime(1212):     at com.example.rssfeed.RssfeedActivity.onCreate(RssfeedActivity.java:12)
09-27 07:08:43.554: E/AndroidRuntime(1212):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
09-27 07:08:43.554: E/AndroidRuntime(1212):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
09-27 07:08:43.554: E/AndroidRuntime(1212):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
09-27 07:08:43.554: E/AndroidRuntime(1212):     ... 11 more
09-27 07:08:43.554: E/AndroidRuntime(1212): Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.example.android.rssfeed.MyListFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
09-27 07:08:43.554: E/AndroidRuntime(1212):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:597)
09-27 07:08:43.554: E/AndroidRuntime(1212):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:561)
09-27 07:08:43.554: E/AndroidRuntime(1212):     at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4778)
09-27 07:08:43.554: E/AndroidRuntime(1212):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
09-27 07:08:43.554: E/AndroidRuntime(1212):     ... 21 more
09-27 07:08:43.554: E/AndroidRuntime(1212): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.android.rssfeed.MyListFragment" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.rssfeed-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.rssfeed-2, /system/lib]]
09-27 07:08:43.554: E/AndroidRuntime(1212):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
09-27 07:08:43.554: E/AndroidRuntime(1212):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
09-27 07:08:43.554: E/AndroidRuntime(1212):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
09-27 07:08:43.554: E/AndroidRuntime(1212):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:583)
09-27 07:08:43.554: E/AndroidRuntime(1212):     ... 24 more
```

RssfeedActivity

```
package com.example.rssfeed;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class RssfeedActivity extends Activity implements MyListFragment.OnItemSelectedListener{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_rssfeed);
    }

    // if the wizard generated an onCreateOptionsMenu you can delete
    // it, not needed for this tutorial

  @Override
  public void onRssItemSelected(String link) {
    DetailFragment fragment = (DetailFragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.detailFragment);
        if (fragment != null && fragment.isInLayout()) {
          fragment.setText(link);
        } 
  }

} 

    package com.example.rssfeed;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DetailFragment extends Fragment {

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
      Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_rssitem_detail,
        container, false);
    return view;
  }

  public void setText(String item) {
    TextView view = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.detailsText);
    view.setText(item);
  }
}
```

MyListFragment

```
    package com.example.rssfeed;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MyListFragment extends Fragment {

  private OnItemSelectedListener listener;

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
      Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_rsslist_overview,
        container, false);
    Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        updateDetail();
      }
    });
    return view;
  }

  public interface OnItemSelectedListener {
      public void onRssItemSelected(String link);
    }

  @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
      super.onAttach(activity);
      if (activity instanceof OnItemSelectedListener) {
        listener = (OnItemSelectedListener) activity;
      } else {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
            + " must implemenet MyListFragment.OnItemSelectedListener");
      }
    }


  // May also be triggered from the Activity
  public void updateDetail() {
    // create fake data
    String newTime = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
    // Send data to Activity
    listener.onRssItemSelected(newTime);
  }
}
```

layout file

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/listFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        class="com.example.android.rssfeed.MyListFragment" ></fragment>
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/detailFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.example.android.rssfeed.DetailFragment" >
        <!-- Preview: layout=@layout/details -->
    </fragment>
</RelativeLayout>

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/detailsText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
        android:text="Default Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="30dip" />

</LinearLayout>
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Press to update" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `MyListFragment` and `DetailFragment` are part of `com.example.rssfeed` package.So in `Fragment` tag change

```
com.example.android.rssfeed.MyListFragment
```

to

```
com.example.rssfeed.MyListFragment
```

and

```
com.example.android.rssfeed.DetailFragment
```

to

```
com.example.rssfeed.DetailFragment
```

i.e. in your layout file,change

```
fragment
        android:id="@+id/listFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        class="com.example.android.rssfeed.MyListFragment" ></fragment>
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/detailFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.example.android.rssfeed.DetailFragment" >
        <!-- Preview: layout=@layout/details -->
    </fragment>
```

to

```
fragment
        android:id="@+id/listFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        class="com.example.rssfeed.MyListFragment" ></fragment>
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/detailFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.example.rssfeed.DetailFragment" >
        <!-- Preview: layout=@layout/details -->
    </fragment>
```